# Vectorize matrix multiplication

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, vectorization

I have a school project about running a SOR algorithm on Octave, but mine is very inefficient. So I have this snippet of code:

```
for ii=1:n
    r = 1/A(ii,ii);
    for jj=1:n
        if (ii!=jj)
            A(ii,jj) = A(ii,jj)*r;
        end;
    end;
    b(ii,1) = b(ii,1)*r;
    x(ii,1) = b(ii,1);
end;
```

How can I vectorize this? My first attempt was this:

```
for ii=1:n
    r = 1/A(ii,ii);
    A(find(eye(length(A))!=1)) = A(find(eye(length(A))!=1))*r;
    b(ii,1) = b(ii,1)*r;
    x(ii,1) = b(ii,1);
end;
```

But I'm not sure it helped much. Is there a better and/or more efficient way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what the code is actually doing? (some matrix factorization maybe...)

Comment: It is creating the iteration matrix of the SOR algorithm.

Comment: Posted a `bsxfun` based solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26128876/3293881) if you would like to take a look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can totally avoid loops I believe. You have to see that you are taking as the reciprocal of diagonal elements of `A`, then why do you want to use a loop. Do it directly. That's the first step. Remove `Inf` and now you want to multiply `r` to corresponding non-diagonal elements of corresponding rows, right?

Therefore, use `repmat` to construct such a matrix which will have replicated elements along columns, since you are multiplying same `r` to (1,2), (1,3), ... , (1,n). But `R` has non-zero diagonal elements. Therefore make them zero. Now you will get your A except that the diagonal elements will be zero. Therefore, you just have to add them back from original `A`. That can be done by `A=A.*R+A.*eye(size(A,1))`.

Vectorization comes from experience and most importantly analyzing your code. Think at each step whether you want to use the loop, if not replace that step with the equivalent command, other code will follow (for example, I constructed a matrix `R`, whereas you were constructing individual elements `r`. So I only thought about converting `r` -> `R` and then the rest of the code will just fall into place).

The code is as follows:

```
R=1./(A.*eye(size(A,1))); %assuming matrix A is square and it does not contain 0 on the main diagonal
R=R(~isinf(R));
R=R(:);
R1=R;
R=repmat(R,[1,size(A,2)]);
R=R.*(true(size(A,1))-eye(size(A,1)));
A=A.*R+A.*eye(size(A,1)); %code verified till here since A comes out to be the same

b = b.*R1;
x=b;
```

Comment: That's amazing, Parag! It does works! Do you have any source where I can learn more about vectorization like this? I'm having a hard time understading what you did and would also like to vectorize the other loops I have in my code!

Comment: @dccarmo I just checked. `b` doesn't come out to be right. Could you see why since you know the code better than me. Or am I doing some mistake. I will try to tell the logic by editing my answer

Comment: I just checked here and b does come out the same as the original code, am I checking it wrong?

Comment: No. If its coming out right for you, then its right, after all its your code.

Comment: just found the problem: b is supposed to be a vector, but it's comming out as a matrix. I'll try to understand and fix what you did! Thanks!

Comment: @dccarmo for me, `b` comes out to be a vector but the values are different. I defined `b` to be a column vector of `size(A,1)` and then ran both the codes. The result for `b` was different. It cannot be a matrix if initially it was a column vector since `R1` is a column vector and `b` is obtained by element-wise multiplication of `b` and `R1`

Answer (score 2):

I suppose there are matrices:

```
A (NxN)
b (Nx1)
```

The code:

```
d = diag(A);
A = diag(1 ./ d) * A + diag(d - 1);
b = b ./ d;
x = b;
```

Answer (score 2):

Randomly bumped onto this problem and at first glance looked interesting given the fact that the problem was tagged as a `vectorization` problem.

I was able to come up with a `bsxfun` based vectorized solution that also uses `diagonal indexing`. This solution seems to give me a `3-4x` speedup over the loop code with decent sized inputs.

Assuming that you are still somewhat interested in seeing speedup improvement on this problem, I would be eager to know the kind of speedups you would be getting with it. Here's the code -

```
diag_ind = 1:size(A,1)+1:numel(A);
diag_A = A(diag_ind(:));
A = bsxfun(@rdivide,A,diag_A);
A(diag_ind) = diag_A;
b(:,1) = b(:,1)./diag_A;
x(:,1) = b(:,1);
```

Let me know!